# Intervalo de datas em outro intervalo de datas

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho duas colunas do tipo *DATETIME*: uma se chama dataHoraSaida e outra dataHoraRetorno em uma tabela chamada viagem.
Eu gostaria de entrar com duas datas (um intervalo) e saber se já existe algum registro nesse intervalo de datas.
Exemplo: gostaria de saber se no intervalo 2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017:01-09 00:00:00 já existe algum registro.

Desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso, monte sua sql dessa forma se quiser comparar apenas a data:

```
SELECT * FROM `viagem` WHERE cast(dataHoraSaidaas DATE) >= '2017-04-10' and cast(dataHoraRetorno DATE) <= '2017-04-15'
```

Se quiser comparar data e hora:

```
SELECT * FROM `viagem` WHERE dataHoraSaidaas >= '2017-04-05 00:00:00' and dataHoraRetorno <= '2017-04-15 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi certo, o que você quer é isso:

```
SELECT *
FROM `viagem`
WHERE dataHoraSaida > '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND dataHoraRetorno < '2017:01-09 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Edite sua resposta orientando o uso do operador `BETWEEN`.